Error while deploying a Firebase Cloud Function disabled previous revisions of the function also
I recently came across a problem where I deployed the Firebase Cloud Functions using command firebase deploy --only functions. There are around 100 functions that are deployed. This time, one of the function didn't deploy properly and I saw the following error:
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    sendPushNotificationHttps(us-central1)

I didn't notice this error and I came to know about this after many users reported that the app is not working as expected. That was because we weren't able to send push notifications to the users because there was some error deploying that function. When I scrolled further up, the only thing that I saw was

Could not create or update Cloud Run service sendpushnotificationhttps. Revision 'sendpushnotificationhttps-00059-xir' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.

There was no code error as such and I just simply deployed the functions again and this time, the deploy went through fine and the app started to work as expected. My question is that there are multiple revisions of each function as I see it in the Logs Explorer and my understanding was that even if there was some deploy error, the previous revisions will continue to work. In this case, when there was no error on my part, they should have definitely continued to work. I deploy functions many times in a week and I simply give the command and get on with other stuff as it takes around 5 mins to deploy all the functions.
How can I avoid this from happening again in the future with an expectation that if there is a deploy error for any function, the previous revisions of the function should continue to work?

I'm not clear.  Are you saying that the previously deployed version didn't work after this error, and you're trying to prevent that from happening again?  If that's the case, then Stack Overflow won't be of much help to you.  We can't really change it's behavior.  File an issue against the Firebase CLI on GitHub if it's not working the way you expect.

@DougStevenson Yes, if the Firebase CLI ran into a problem deploying a function, it shouldn't completely shut down the service. Like I mentioned, there was no code error and the function deployed successfully when I retried it but the push notification service was down till the retry was successful. In my case, since I didn't notice the error, it was down for more than a day. Are you saying that this is the expected behavior?

No, I'm saying you have a valid request for the CLI, and the only way things will change is if you contact Firebase directly to make the request.  The volunteers of Stack Overflow can't do anything for you.

@DougStevenson Okay, I will open a bug request on Firebase support.
